# Super Strong Magnets

Tags: electromagnetism

I've seen the size of electric motors get smaller over the past 10-15 years...especially those used in small remote control vehicles like helicopters.  I heard that the magnets being used in the motors are special exotic materials like neodymium. What is present at the atomic- and/or molecular-level which makes these materials have such strong magnetic properties?

Comment: incomplete f orbitals if I remember right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling "Why are neodymium magnets so strong" led me to the following explanation:

> Neodymium may the rare earth metal neodymium magnets are named for,
>   but the magnets themselves are actually an alloy of iron, boron and
>   neodymium. The magnet's chemical composition is typically Nd2Fe14B, a
>   composition that forms a tetragonal crystal structure. This structure
>   has what is called exceptionally high uniaxial magnetocrystalline
>   anisotropy--as high as HA~7 Tesla. In layman's terms, this means
>   neodymium magnets' atoms are arranged in such a way as that the
>   **electron spin is permanently and very strongly aligned in a given
>   direction**, giving the compound the extreme magnetic force for which
>   it's famous.

It sounds plausible - a combination of atomic and crystal structure properties makes lots of little current loops "point the same way". I realize this is just the start of an answer: *why* atoms in this configuration want to align their electron orbitals in this way requires a deeper quantum-mechanical explanation - I will leave it to others to provide that, but you might find http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1010&context=mechengdiss a good starting point.

Source of quote: http://www.ehow.com/about_5297656_neodymium-magnets-strong.html